# Compiling a shader using c++ (LNK2019 Error)

Tags: opengl, compilation

I'm trying to create a simple Arnold Renderer shader using visual studio based on the tutorial below. https://support.solidangle.com/display/mayatut/Creating+a+shader

I have created a `win32console` application with the application type set to DLL  and have added my include libraries and ai.lib to the linker input.

When I try to compile the shader I'm met with

Error 1: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__AiNodeParamRGB referenced in function "void __cdecl Parameters(struct AtList *,struct AtMetaDataStore *)" (?Parameters@@YAXPAUAtList@@PAUAtMetaDataStore@@@Z)    C:\Users\matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj ConsoleApplication2`

Error 2: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__AiShaderEvalParamFuncRGB referenced in function "void __cdecl Evaluate(struct AtNode *,struct AtShaderGlobals *)" (?Evaluate@@YAXPAUAtNode@@PAUAtShaderGlobals@@@Z)  C:\Users\matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj ConsoleApplication2`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to link a 64-bit library (ai.lib) to create a 32-bit dll. In other words, the linker is complaining because it doesn't understand the ai.lib architecture. The mismatch between 64 and 32-bit architectures are causing the problem. If your system is 32-bit, you can't compile the shader. If you have a 64bit system, you can set VC++ to build and compile a 64-bit dll.

On the tool bar in VC++
click on Win32 (next to debug), and open the drop-down menu. 
Choose configuration manager, and under platform drop-down menu, choose x64. 
Clean and build again.